# Why does Kali Linux prompt me for username and password I did not create

Tags: kali-linux

I just started using Kali Linux and I decided to run it on VM ware rather than installing as an OS, the weird thing about it that its asking me to login using my username and password. On first installation it did not even ask to create such account, can somebody plz help me deal with this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Here's default username and password for Kali Linux i386, amd64, VMWare and ARM images
(older versions)

username: root

password: toor

(latest version, since the release of 2020.1)

username: kali

password: kali

Tell me if one of them works. Cheers!

References: 
[https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/kali-linux-default-passwords/#:~:text=During%20installation%2C%20Kali%20Linux%20allows,toor%22%2C%20without%20the%20quotes.](https:////www.kali.org/docs/introduction/kali-linux-default-passwords/#:%7E:text=During%20installation%2C%20Kali%20Linux%20allows,toor%22%2C%20without%20the%20quotes.)

https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/default-credentials/

Answer (score -1):

May be you have installed it in virtual machine so

1. May be not installed correctly try to reinstall but I suggest to install it as os not vm ware.
2. Try to use username and password you gave on VMware.
   3)Try to use your root name as username and same as password.

May be this will work try it and let me know!

Regards,
Swayam S.K

Comment: It's not an answer, just some guess. You are also suggesting without knowing all the facts.